# Cannot instantiate my own class: no matching function for call to 'DHT::DHT()'

Tags: arduino, refactoring, arduino-c++

I am writing an **Arduino** project and try to wrap my own class around the DHT (Sensor) library (https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/master/examples/DHT_Unified_Sensor/DHT_Unified_Sensor.ino or that https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/master/examples/DHTtester/DHTtester.ino).

I wanna abstract my own Library with functions and use that to learn C++.

But I have a problem when I try to instantiate my own class:

```
lib/Hythe/Hythe.cpp: In constructor 'Hythe::Hythe(uint8_t, uint8_t)':
lib/Hythe/Hythe.cpp:3:47: error: no matching function for call to 'DHT::DHT()'
 Hythe::Hythe(uint8_t dht_pin, uint8_t dht_type)
```

**Can someone please tell me how to declare, instantiate and call the DHT class within my own class?** 
When I implement DHT

main.cpp

```
#include "Hythe.h"
Hythe hythe(HYTHE_PIN, HYTHE_TYPE); // here I instantiate the sensor.

void setup()
{
  hythe.getSensorInfo();
}
```

Hythe.h

```
#include "SPI.h"
#include "Wire.h"
#include <DHT.h>

class Hythe
{
private:
    float temperature;
    float humidity;
    uint32_t delayMS;
public:
    Hythe(uint8_t, uint8_t);        // init with PIN and TYPE
    DHT _dht; // THIS IS CAUSING THE ERROR
    // (It's in the header file. I simply wanna declare it and
    // call it in the cpp file later).
    // When I remove this line I get: 
    // "error: '_dht' was not declared in this scope"

    unsigned char getTemperature(); // read the temperature
    void getSensorInfo();           // returns sensor info

};
```

Hythe.cpp

```
#include "Hythe.h"

Hythe::Hythe(uint8_t dht_pin, uint8_t dht_type)
{
    Serial.print(dht_pin);
    _dht = DHT(dht_pin, dht_type);
}

unsigned char Hythe::getTemperature()
{
    return 0;
}

void Hythe::getSensorInfo()
{
    Serial.println(F("------------------------------------"));
    Serial.println(F("Temperature Sensor"));
}
```

Comment: It means for example that there is no default constructor for the class DHT used ub tge declaration DHT _dht;;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Vlad points out, `DHT` has no default constructor. You want to use [initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list) to avoid calling a default constructor. You can directly call DHT's constructor in the initializer list this way.

```cpp
Hythe::Hythe(uint8_t dht_pin, uint8_t dht_type): _dht(dht_pin, dht_type)
{
    Serial.print(dht_pin);
}
```